# CSS clear both inside children

Tags: css, css-float

I'm getting troubles with this issue for a long time. I believe that it's a quite common problem for float layout and I wish someone would give a "standard" solution.

As title, the problem is about nested floats. Consider the following simple layout:

```
<div class='parent clearfix'>
     <div id='child1' style='float:left; width:500px'>
         { ... child 1 content goes here ... }
     </div>
     <div id='child2' style='margin-left:501px;'>
         { ... child 2 content goes here ... }
     </div>
</div>
```

Here **clearfix** is a common technique for auto clearing floated children. The problem is, the layout is broken if **child2** contains another **clearfix** element. For example, if child 2 content is:

```
<div class='inside clearfix'>
    <div class='sub1' style='float-left; width:100px'> 
        { ... extra content goes here ... } 
    </div>
    <div class='sub2' style='margin-left:101px'> 
        { ... extra content goes here ... } 
    </div>
</div>
```

So generally, if we use **clear:both** **inside** a floated layout (inside the non-floated element), it also clears the parent container.

I know how to do it if using absolute position and a bit of js, but it's not a good practice.

How to fix it using **float**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also use overflow: hidden;

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="float"></div>
  <div class="float"></div>
</div>

.wrapper{
 overflow: hidden;
}

.float{float: left;}
```

check demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xdfc/)

Comment: Overflow:hidden is the most mysterious thing in CSS! I suppose that clear:both is pretty redundant.

Answer (score 1):

While working with floats, i follow a simpler approach of using an extra div with class clear. This is much easier, understandable and less error prone.

Following is what i do :

```
<div class="parentClass">
    <div class="float1">
    . . .  
    </div>
    <div class="float2">
    . . .
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

In CSS, the clear class is like following :

```
.clear { clear:both; overflow:hidden; }
```

You can try this approach and I am sure things will pane out good. Best of luck !

Comment: This method doesn't give a full 100% width (adding float1 and float2), and you need to use JS. Also, if you have to use <b>float</b> and <b>clear:both</b> again in float2 element, it breaks the layout. This is the question I want to ask.